# Sort array with nested dictionaries by string values that contain floats

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, dictionary

What i have is

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorNearest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"petrolStation.pointCoordinates.distance" ascending:YES];
_nearestList = (NSMutableArray *)[_gasStations sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptorNearest]];
```

after this, `_nearestList` is sorted by a string compare of the distances:

```
distance: 11242.591384
distance: 11255.886503
distance: 11473.600818
distance: 11547.162685
distance: 11772.008008
distance: 11838.271283
distance: 12012.219580
distance: 12054.000451
distance: 12775.864654
distance: 13878.021040
distance: 14941.605403
distance: 15011.424101
distance: 1513.702794
distance: 17359.161771
distance: 1795.865052
distance: 19494.251275
distance: 19494.821685
```

But i want to sort by the float values. How can i achieve this?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it :)

```
NSComparator compareDistances = ^(id string1, id string2)
{
    NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[string1 floatValue]];
    NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[string2 floatValue]];

    return [number1 compare:number2];
};

// sort list and create nearest list
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorNearest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"petrolStation.pointCoordinates.distance" ascending:YES comparator:compareDistances];
_nearestList = (NSMutableArray *)[_gasStations sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptorNearest]];
```